# Div onscroll end detection not working consistently

Tags: javascript, reactjs, infinite-scroll

I have a simple implementation of infinte scroll in React.js. I am using `event.target.scrollHeight` to detect the end of the div.
But its not working consistently across the browsers.
For instance the when I make the height of the div as 30vh it works in chrome but not in firefox.
If I make it 35vh it works in firefox but not in chrome.

I know I can use the reference tag method also, but whats wrong in this approach.

Full code : https://codesandbox.io/s/simple-infinite-scroll-vei7g 
Code file : demo.js

Comment: is the problem only with "vh" or also with other "px" values? I am unable to recreate the issue. which browser versions are you using ?

Comment: I am using firefox 69.0.2, chrome 77.0.3865.90. Its also happening with px. If I make the height as 100px it works in firefox, not chrome.

Comment: you should try using intersection observer instead of listening to scroll event. much more performant. [here is an example,](https://vueschool.io/articles/vuejs-tutorials/build-an-infinite-scroll-component-using-intersection-observer-api/) this is for vue.js but it should work the same way in reactjs

Comment: it is an experimental API

Comment: @cloned As I wrote, I can use react reference tag, but I want to know whats wrong here.

Comment: It's experimental but it's also implemented in every major browser. so if react supports the browser it also supports IO. Also there is a polyfill that uses scroll event listeners (but this may result in bad performance) ... So i just suggest to rewrite OPs code with a modern solution https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the problem with your condition. What I noticed from the console is `firefox` gives the value which is equal to `(e.target.scrollHeight - e.target.scrollTop) - 1`. This makes`e.target.scrollHeight - e.target.scrollTop === e.target.clientHeight` condition to return `false`. So, I just changed the condition to `e.target.scrollHeight <= e.target.scrollTop + e.target.clientHeight`. And it works fine in both the browsers.

```
  const isScrolling = e => {
    const tData =
    e.target.scrollHeight <= e.target.scrollTop + e.target.clientHeight;
    console.log("scrolling.....", divHeight, tData);

    if (tData) {
      fetchMoreListItems();
    }
  };
```

And same by using `ref`.

```
  const isScrolling = () => {
    const tData =
      scrollCont.current.scrollTop + scrollCont.current.clientHeight >=
      scrollCont.current.scrollHeight;
    console.log("scrolling.....", divHeight, tData);
    if (tData) {
      fetchMoreListItems();
    }
  };
```

Here is the [codepen](https://codesandbox.io/s/simple-infinite-scroll-tddbu) which uses the `ref` implementation.

Comment: Testing it out. BTW what should be the approach performance wise?

Comment: I'll say, you don't really need the `refs` for your use case. As you already have the necessary variables in `event` object. `Refs` are recommended only when you don't have any other means to access the `DOM` object.